# Convert Pandas df Column to JSON String

Tags: python, json, pandas

Having the following pandas dataframe:

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3]})
```

It looks like:

```
    bar foo
0    1   a
1    2   b
2    3   c
```

How could I get for every row the following string pattern:`

```
{"telemetry":{"a":1}}
```

Comment: Can you add complete expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with dictionary:

```
a = [{"telemetry":{a:b}} for a, b in df[['foo','bar']].to_numpy()]
print (a)
[{'telemetry': {'a': 1}}, {'telemetry': {'b': 2}}, {'telemetry': {'c': 3}}]
```

If need jsons:

```
import json

b = [json.dumps({"telemetry":{a:b}}) for a, b in df[['foo','bar']].to_numpy()]
print (b)
['{"telemetry": {"a": 1}}', '{"telemetry": {"b": 2}}', '{"telemetry": {"c": 3}}']
```

---

```
c = json.dumps([{"telemetry":{a:b}} for a, b in df[['foo','bar']].to_numpy()])
print (c)
[{"telemetry": {"a": 1}}, {"telemetry": {"b": 2}}, {"telemetry": {"c": 3}}]
```